# Server/Client соединение между ПК и Android через беспроводную точку доступа

Tags: java, android, сокет

Решил разобраться с программированием сокетов между пк и андроид. Через консоль создал беспроводную точку доступа на пк и приконнектил к ней смартфон. Написал тестовый сервер на java:

```
public void socketConnection() {
    int port = 6666;

    try {
        ServerSocket ss =
                new ServerSocket(port, 0, java.net.InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.102"));
        System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Got a client :) ... Finally, someone saw me through all the cover!");
        System.out.println();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Далее я написал клиент для андроид:

```
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        SenderThread sender = new SenderThread();
        sender.execute();
    }

    class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            socketConn();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void socketConn() {
        int serverPort = 6666;
        String address = "192.168.1.102";

        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); /
            System.out.println("Any of you heard of a socket with IP address " + address + " and port " + serverPort + "?");
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort);
            System.out.println("Yes! I just got hold of the program.");
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            et.setText("Yes! I just got hold of the program.");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Решил протестить и вылетел такой exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.102 (port 6666): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Какие возможные причины или может изначально что то не так?

Comment: попробуйте использовать конструктор `ServerSocket(int port)`

Comment: Может просто порт на сервере закрыт фаерволом?